# Can I drive LVCMOS12 on Xilinx Artix-7 at 100 Mbps?

Tags: fpga, gpio, termination, artix-series-fpga, lvcmos

I'm currently planning a setup as shown below, where I need to operate the GPIO on my chip at a data rate of 100 Mbps. My biggest concern is whether it is a feasible to drive LVCMOS12 on Xilinx Artix-7 FPGA at 100 Mbps. Although I was not able to find a specification for the LVCMOS12 on Xilinx Artix-7 FPGA, but came across the datasheet for Microsemi's SmartFusion12 ([Link](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_download/132042-igloo2-fpga-datasheet)). The datasheet indicates that LVCMOS12 on SmartFusion12 can drive up to 120 Mbps for MSIO I/O bank, but wonder if this applies to Xilinx Artix-7 FPGA as well.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could share your experience regarding this or have any concern regarding the setup I have in the figure.

[image]

Comment: I once had a similar question. It seems impossible to find any specification for the maximum I/O rate on these devices.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, 100 Mbps should be no problem. I have an Artix-7 design that's driving the four lanes of a [CameraLink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_Link) interface at 595 Mbps in each lane. I'm using LVDS_25, but the physical pin properties for LVCMOS12 shouldn't be all that different.

I'm also receiving a very similar interface from a sensor chip at about 480 Mbps per lane.

The I/O switching characteristics are found in [DS181](https://docs.xilinx.com/v/u/en-US/ds181_Artix_7_Data_Sheet), pages 23-24.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your experience!